# Zorn's Lemma in the proof of Riesz representation theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, riesz-representation-theorem

I was reading the wikipedia article of the representation theorem of Riesz–Fréchet.

see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem

In the proof of the theorem, they say

> "Using Zorn's lemma or the well-ordering theorem it can be shown that
> there exists some non-zero vector $v\in M^{\perp}$"

$M$ denotes just the kernel of the functional $f\in\mathcal{H}^{\prime}$, which is assumed to be non-zero.

I am wondering why we need the Lemma of Zorn for this statement. I have had a look at different books about functional analysis and litarally nobody mentions this. Also a google search gives no result. I mean since we assume that $f$ is non-zero, we know that the kernel $M$ is not the whole Hilbert space and hence, the orthogonal complement $M^{\perp}$ is not empty and contains a non-trivial element by the projection theorem, which says that $\mathcal{H}=M\oplus M^{\perp}$.

Comment: Yes, this is certainly not choice-dependent (apart from maybe countable choice or something), and the projection theorem (a much more important and relevant result in this situation) solves this part.

Comment: Okay great thanks!